# Copying file from a Samba drive to an Android sdcard directory

Tags: android, file, copy, sd-card, samba

I am new to Android and Samba. I am trying to use the JCIFS copy. To method to copy a file from a Samba directory to the 'Download' directory under sdcard on an Android 3.1 device. Following is my code:

```
from = new SmbFile("smb://username:password@a.b.c.d/sandbox/sambatosdcard.txt");
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File sourceFile = new File(root + "/Download", "SambaCopy.txt");
to = new SmbFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
from.copyTo(to);
```

I am getting a MalformedURLException on the 'to' file. Is there a way to get around this problem using the `copyTo` method, or is there an alternate way to copy a file from the samba folder to the sdcard folder using JCIFS or any other way?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any message in the exception that could be of help?

Comment: This is the message I see in LogCat: "11-17 08:52:00.178: W/System.err(639): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /mnt/sdcard/Download/SambaCopy.txt"

Comment: I had to use the SMBFileInputStream and the regular java FileOutputStream to copy the file, as in here:http://sambaexplorer.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/DownloadService.java

Comment: This will help you .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775656/copy-all-files-from-server-to-android-device

Answer (score 2):

The SmbFile's `copyTo()` method lets you copy files from network to network. To copy files between your local device and the network you need to use streams. E.g.:

```
try {
    SmbFile source = 
            new SmbFile("smb://username:password@a.b.c.d/sandbox/sambatosdcard.txt");

    File destination = 
            new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SambaCopy.txt");

    InputStream in = source.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);

    // Copy the bits from Instream to Outstream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    // Maybe in.close();
    out.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```