# Make SmbFile from Android SDCard

Tags: android, smb

I need to access the android SDCard file to copy it to the windows shared folder. I'm unable to make SMBFile from Android SDCard. Currently I'm using this:

```
    SmbFile smbFile_Source = new SmbFile("smb:///mnt/sdcard/abc.jpg");

    smbFile_Source.length();

    SmbFile smbFile_dest = new SmbFile("smb://192.x.x.x/folder/abc.jpg", authentication);

    smbFile_Source.copyTo(smbFile_dest);
```

The destination smbfile is working fine..Only I can't make file from Android SDcard..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will probably have to make the source file a File object not an smb object, then use an input and output stream to save your file to the smb file location

[Copying file from a Samba drive to an Android sdcard directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169593/copying-file-from-a-samba-drive-to-an-android-sdcard-directory)

Comment: Thanks a bunch dear...Your answer solved my problem...!!
God Bless..:)

Comment: hey Tantonj!
Can you tell me how to mount sdcard as network drive which can be accessed from PC?? I've search a lot but couldn't help myself.

Comment: funny you ask this, i was just thinking of a way to do this today, but i haven't done the research yet, i'll get back to ya... one thing though, is i can't test yet, cuz my tablets usb cord stopped working for data transmission so i am programming free til one comes from china... but i am gunna quickly look right now

Comment: what do you want to do with this? just host it to your network so pcs can interact with it? or are you doing anything special with it.  Cuz there are already apps out there that let you host a directory on the network, i think...
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-access-sd-card-system-files-on-android-from-your-comuputer/
but this is mostly ftp instead

Comment: http://androidcommander.com/?file_id=13
this windows app looks wicked, can't set it up til my new cord comes in, but it works wirelessly too.  if only this app set up a wifi debug link, then you could program wirelessly :D  however device must be rooted, i haven't decided to do that yet

Comment: sorry for late reply, as it was weekend.
And Yes I want to host it as shared folder on network like we do in PC's. I don't want already available apps but to include it in my own app.

Comment: hmmm, well as far as i can tell, it can't be done with jcifs.  And I don't know any thing else that does network stuff with android.  But this can definitely be done on windows' end.  just like that windows app i linked you, the guys facebook page is linked on there.  you could ask him if you end up going windows' end.