# Reading information from CIFS / SMB with an Android application

Tags: android, smb, jcifs

I've been attempting to develop an android application that can pull information from a CIFS / SMB protocol. I've tried JCIFS and keep getting errors with my eclipse application not being able to read the package (even after I've Javadoc'd it), and my last resort was to get help. Therefore, can anyone offer incite / information on how to do this?

I've tried this : [Copy all files from server to Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775656/copy-all-files-from-server-to-android-device)

I've tried this : http://jcifs.samba.org/

I've tried this: http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/01/adding-jcifs-api-to-our-android-java.html

Maybe there is a couple things I'm not understanding at the moment that could be fleshed out.

My snippet of the code I'm using (copy and pasted directly from the third link for the most part) :

```
public void login(String address2, String username2, String password2)
        throws Exception {
    setDomain(UniAddress.getByName(address2));
    setAuthentication(new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(address2, username2,
            password2));
    SmbSession.logon(getDomain(), authentication);
}

public UniAddress getDomain() {
    return domain;
}

/**
 * @param domain
 *            the domain to set
 */
public void setDomain(UniAddress domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
}

/**
 * @return the authentication
 */
public NtlmPasswordAuthentication getAuthentication() {
    return authentication;
}

/**
 * @param authentication
 *            the authentication to set
 */
public void setAuthentication(NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication) {
    this.authentication = authentication;
}
```

and then from here I'm calling the login(); with a address, username, and password. When I do this the application crashes and gives me an error of "NoClassDefFoundError" at the line: setDomain(UniAddress....), specifically from the UniAddress class.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that you have followed the procedure from:

http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/01/adding-jcifs-api-to-our-android-java.html

in importing `jcifs.jar` for `UniAddress` and other jcifs apis,
but for it to work :

> `jcifs.jar` must be present in `<Project Name>/libs` folder